# Select Top 3 then select alphabetically high customer if all customers have same DOB else all three

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

it is random skill question i was trying to attempt

```
Create Table Customer(
ID Int Not Null
,Name Varchar(20)
,Email Nvarchar(100)
,DOB Datetime)
--10,000,000 records inserted
```

Ques.  Find the 3rd youngest customer from this table based on date only (time excluded).

If there are multiple customers with same DOB at third place, 
then the one higher in alphabetical order by name should only be returned.

E.g. if below are 3 customers at 3rd spot with same DOB, 
then only one record with the name Alanso should be returned.

```
Name    DOB
Peter   1980/1/1
Mark    1980/1/1
Alanso  1980/1/1
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The solution will be slightly different for each as some support `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` and others support window functions, etc.

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Just to clarify.. Let's say there are 5 people tied with the same *youngest* date.  Would you want one of these 5 people to be returned as the third youngest based on name?

Answer (score 3):

```
with rnk as (
    select Name,
        dense_rank() over (order by DOB desc) as dr,
        row_number() over (partition by DOB order by Name) as rn
    from Customer
)
select Name from rnk
where dr = 3 and rn = 1;
```

Classically we did things like this:

```
select Name from Customer c
where
    (
    select count(distinct DOB) from Customer c2
    where c2.DOB <= c.DOB
    ) = 3
    and
    (
    select count(*) from Customer c2
    where c2.DOB = c.DOB and c2.Name <= c.Name
    ) = 1;
```

Comment: An improvement over my answer, since you do it with just one subquery +1.

Comment: Nice simplifaction of @TimBiegeleisen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to apply analytic functions twice.  First, we can apply `DENSE_RANK` on your table, ordering by the date component of the date of birth, to identify all records tied for 3rd youngest.  Then, we can subquery that result and use `ROW_NUMBER` ordered ascending by name to find the record you want to retain.

```
SELECT
    ID, NAME, EMAIL, DOB
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, DOB)) dr
        FROM yourTable
    ) t
    WHERE dr = 3
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```